# Error serializar Json clase abstracta

Tags: c#, json, windows-forms, signalr

Estoy intentando mandar una lista de objetos abstractos a trabes de `signalr`

Estructura servidor (donde se generan todos los valores);

```
public abstract class Comida : Objeto
{
    public int valorNutricional;
    public abstract void Comido(Cola jugador);
}
```

La clase objeto establece la x y la y Esta clase tiene 2 hijos que son;

```
class ComidaNormal : Comida
{

    public ComidaNormal(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.ancho = 20;
        valorNutricional = 1;
    }
}

class ComidaEnvenenada : Comida
{

    public ComidaEnvenenada(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.ancho = 20;
    }
}
```

Segun el flujo de ejecucion se instanciarán ;

```
public static List<Comida> comidas = new List<Comida>();
comidas.Add(new ComidaEnvenenada(x, y));
comidas.Add(new ComidaNormal(x, y));
```

Todo funciona perfectamente hasta la hora de tener que enviarle esa lista de `comidas` al cliente;

Metodo servidor;

```
    public List<Comida> getComida()
    {
        return comidas;
    }
```

Metodo cliente;

```
comidas = await ApiConexion._hub.Invoke<List<Comida>>("getComida");
```

saltando el siguiente error en esta ultima linea de codigo.

Error;

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Could not create an instance of type Snake.Comida. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated.'

Comment: Buenas, te recomiendo que leas [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30349695/could-not-create-an-instance-of-type-x-type-is-an-interface-or-abstract-class-a) pregunta!

Comment: Revisa este post, tienen el mismo problema que comentas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30349695/could-not-create-an-instance-of-type-x-type-is-an-interface-or-abstract-class-a

Comment: @VictorPerdomo lo mandaste a leer el mismo post que juan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La solución a este problema es configurar el deserializador para que **use la información en el json**. No es lo que se usa por defecto.

La serialización se hace de esta forma:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer();
serializer.Converters.Add(new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.JavaScriptDateTimeConverter());
serializer.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
serializer.TypeNameHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameHandling.Auto;
serializer.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName))
using (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter writer = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextWriter(sw))
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, obj, typeof(MyDocumentType));
}
```

Al deserializar, los parámetros para `TypeNameHandling` se deben setear:

```
MyDocumentType  obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyDocumentType>(File.ReadAllText(fileName), new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings 
{ 
    TypeNameHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameHandling.Auto,
    NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore,
});
```

> Respuesta original extraída desde [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30350047/73749)